# Get element added after saving Autogenerated form from the Navigator Save Button

Tags: c#, sql-server, winforms

I want to get the element added after saving my form from the navigator save button, I have this code

```
private void destinationBindingNavigatorSaveItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    this.Validate();
    this.destinationBindingSource.EndEdit();
    this.tableAdapterManager.UpdateAll(this.gpaDataSet2);
}
```

Can any one help me thanks